# Android Parcel: Writing an array list

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

Does writing an ArrayList to a parcel create a copy of the list when you read it back? My custom objects are Parcelable and I make sure I don't create copies. I need to be able to pass an ArrayList forward to other activities through intents and I need to be able to add and remove elements in the ArrayList in other activities.

Right now it seems like Parcel creates a copy of the ArrayList therefore I am not able to easily update the elements.

Comment: I don't think this should be possible. If you want to have a shared element for couple of activities make it `static` or somehow outside of activities. Parceling is actually making the class instance capable of being copied.

Comment: No this is not possible by using parcelable. And don't make it static, use proper architecture like a ViewModel, a Repository, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Parcel` serializes and deserializes the data. This makes copies. If you need to share the original objects then you can declare references to them as `static`, which can be accessed from all classes.